# Fibonnaci sequence Golden ratio in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I try to program a fibonacci sequence, which stops after the division of a Fibonacci number divided by its immediate predecessor approximates the Golden Ratio with less than 0.001 difference. However, the code below doesn't seem to be working and don't know why. Thanks in advance!

```
GoldenRatio=(1+sqrt(5))/2
i=3
fib=c(1,1)
while(fib[i-1]/fib[i-2]-GoldenRatio>0.001){
fib[i] <- fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]
i=i+1}
print(fib)
length(fib)
```

Comment: You need to compare absolute difference `abs(fib[i-1]/fib[i-2]-GoldenRatio)`

Comment: Aah got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GoldenRatio=(1+sqrt(5))/2
# 1.618034
i=3
fib=c(1,1)
while(abs(fib[i-1]/fib[i-2]-GoldenRatio)>0.001){
  fib[i] <- fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]
  i=i+1
}
print(fib)
# [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
length(fib)
# [1] 10
print(i)
# 11
print(fib[i-1]/fib[i-2])
# [1] 1.617647
print(abs(fib[i-1]/fib[i-2] - GoldenRatio))
# [1] 0.0003869299
```

Also, as we can see from below, convergence is obtained quite fast:

```
fib=c(1,1)
ratio <- c()
for (i in 3:20) {
  ratio <- c(ratio, fib[i-1]/fib[i-2])
  fib[i] <- fib[i-1]+fib[i-2]
  i=i+1
}
plot(ratio, pch=19,col='red')
lines(ratio, pch=19,col='red')
abline(h=GoldenRatio, col='blue')
legend('topright', legend=c('f(i)/f(i+1)', 'GoldenRatio'), col=c('red', 'blue'), lwd=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Compare the absolute difference

```
GoldenRatio = (1+sqrt(5))/2
i = 3
fib = c(1,1)
while ( abs(fib[i-1]/fib[i-2] - GoldenRatio) > 0.001) {
    fib[i] <- fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
    i = i+1
    }
print(fib)
length(fib)
```